# How to write a csv from a text?

Tags: python, regex, text, concatenation

I'm trying to extract some information from a archive using Python. One part of this archive is:

```
1. [HG-U133_Plus_2] Affymetrix Human Genome U133 Plus 2.0 Array
(Submitter supplied) Affymetrix submissions are replicated on the GeneChip Human Genome U133 Plus 2.0 Array. more...
Organism:   Homo sapiens
527 DataSets 4123 Series 54 Related Platforms 115874 Samples
FTP download: GEO ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/platforms/GPLnnn/GPL570/
Platform    Accession: GPL570   ID: 100000570

2. [Mouse430_2] Affymetrix Mouse Genome 430 2.0 Array
(Submitter supplied) Affymetrix submissions are typically Array. more...
Organism:   Mus musculus
517 DataSets 3529 Series 36 Related Platforms 46528 Samples
FTP download: GEO ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/platforms/GPL1nnn/GPL1261/
Platform    Accession: GPL1261  ID: 100001261
```

```
import re
import sys
import itertools

stdout = open("results.txt", "w")
pattern = re.compile(r'^\d+[.]\s')
pattern2 = re.compile(r'Organism:')
pattern3 = re.compile(r'FTP download:')
pattern4 = re.compile(r'ID: ')

listOrg = []

def group_separator(line):
    return line=='ID: '

with open('Microarray/PlatformsMicroarray.txt') as f:
    for key,group in itertools.groupby(f,group_separator):
        # print(key,list(group))  # uncomment to see what itertools.groupby does.
        if not key:
            data={}
            for item in group:
                for line in f:
                   if pattern.search(line):
                        listOrg.append(line)
                   if pattern2.search(line):
                        #field,value=line.split(':')
                        listOrg.append(line)
                   if pattern3.search(line):
                        listOrg.append(line)
                   if pattern4.search(line):
                        listOrg.append(line)

for item in listOrg:
  stdout.write("%s" % item)

stdout.close()
```

How can I concatenate the information in order to write a archive in .csv?

Comment: What does your `listOrg` look like?

Comment: Organism: Homo sapiens
FTP download: GEO ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/platforms/GPLnnn/GPL570/
Platform Accession: GPL570 ID: 100000570
2. [Mouse430_2] Affymetrix Mouse Genome 430 2.0 Array
Organism: Mus musculus
FTP download: GEO ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/platforms/GPL1nnn/GPL1261/
Platform Accession: GPL1261 ID: 100001261

Comment: Your indentation's all messed up, but I think I've got what you're looking for

Comment: to organize the data in .csv I'm trying split some information before ':' like these: ID, Organism (in fact this info are columns). I tried .slip (#field,value=line.split(':')) but did't work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

the `csv` module is your weapon of choice.

```
with open("path/to/out.csv", "wb") as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for line in whatever_your_input_is:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

In this case it looks like `listOrg` is your parsed input, so you'd do

```
...
    for line in listOrg:
        writer.writerow(line)
```